# CookieManager is not saving my cookies [Android - HttpUrlConnection]

Tags: android, cookies, session-cookies, httpurlconnection

In short, I am getting the PHPSESSID, storing it, but when I want to load it, it's telling me that I have no cookies. I know that I need to store this phpsession id in the cookiestore, so that I can use it all throughout my application. Should I save it somewhere else like SQLite or something like that?

`PostJson` class

```
/**
 * Created by mohammadghali on 9/22/18.
 */

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.icu.text.MessageFormat;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Debug;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import okhttp3.Cookie;


public class PostJson extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> {
    String server_response;

public OnPostTaskDoneListener mListener;
URL url;
static final String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";

boolean alreadyLoggedIn = false;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    try{

        if(strings[0].toLowerCase().equals("true")){
            alreadyLoggedIn = true;
        }
    }catch (Exception err){
        return null;
    }
    this.alreadyLoggedIn = alreadyLoggedIn;


    Log.i("ALREADY LOGGED?: ", alreadyLoggedIn+"");


    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(strings[1]);

        Log.i("URL POST: ",  strings[1]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        CookieManager msCookieManager = new CookieManager();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(msCookieManager);




        if(strings.length>2)
        AddParams(urlConnection, getParamsFromString(strings[2]));

        try {
            if (msCookieManager.getCookieStore().get(url.toURI()).size() > 0) {
                for (HttpCookie cookie : msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()) {
                    Log.i("LOADING COOKIE: ", cookie.getName() + ": " + cookie.getValue());
                }
                // While joining the Cookies, use ',' or ';' as needed. Most of the servers are using ';'
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",
                        TextUtils.join(";", msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
            } else {
                Log.i("LOADING COOKIE: ", "No cookies were found");
            }
        }catch (Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }






        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        Log.i("RESPONSE CODE POST: ",  responseCode+"");
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);


            //Save the cookies
            Map<String, List<String>> headerFields = urlConnection.getHeaderFields();
            List<String> cookiesHeader = headerFields.get(COOKIES_HEADER);



            if (cookiesHeader != null) {
                if (!alreadyLoggedIn) {
                    msCookieManager.getCookieStore().removeAll();
                    Log.i("COOKIE: ", "Cleared all cookies");
                }

                for (String cookie : cookiesHeader) {
                    Log.i("COOKIE: ", cookie);
                    if (!alreadyLoggedIn) {
                        try {
                            msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(url.toURI(), HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
                        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }



            }

            for(HttpCookie cookie : msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()){
                Log.i("STORED COOKIE: ", cookie.getName() +": "+cookie.getValue());
            }


        }else{
            Log.e("failed", "FAILED! Error code: "+responseCode);
            return "FAILED! Error code: "+responseCode;
        }




    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return server_response;


    //return "This is the response";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    Log.i("POST: ",  "EXECUTING ON POST EXEC: "+s);
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    Log.e("Response", "" + server_response);

    mListener.onPostTaskDone(s);

}

private String readStream(InputStream in) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return response.toString();
}

public String getParamsFromMap(Map<String, String> params) {
    String paramsAsString = "";
    for(String key: params.keySet()){
        paramsAsString+=key+"@:@"+params.get(key)+"@-@";//This will be used to separate the stings later so it has to be somehow unique

    }
    Log.i("Params", paramsAsString);
    return paramsAsString;
}

public Map getParamsFromString(String paramsAsString){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try{
        for(String parameter : paramsAsString.split("@-@")){
            map.put(parameter.split("@:@")[0], parameter.split("@:@")[1]);
        }
        return map;

    }catch (Exception err){
        Log.e("Failed", "Failed to convert params: "+err.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

private String getPostDataString(Map<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}

protected HttpURLConnection AddParams(HttpURLConnection urlConnection, Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {

    OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(getPostDataString(params));

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    return urlConnection;
}




public interface OnPostTaskDoneListener {
    void onPostTaskDone(String responseData);

    void onError();
}

}
```

when I logged in and got my session id, but couldn't load it.

Here's is the log:

```
12-02 12:14:08.472 19151-19151/? I/adghali.petsap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-02 12:14:08.537 19151-19151/? W/adghali.petsap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
12-02 12:14:08.802 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/adghali.petsap: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
12-02 12:14:09.122 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
12-02 12:14:09.124 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/chatty: uid=10088(com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp) identical 6 lines
12-02 12:14:09.124 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
12-02 12:14:09.125 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
12-02 12:14:09.125 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/chatty: uid=10088(com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp) identical 1 line
12-02 12:14:09.125 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
12-02 12:14:09.215 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
12-02 12:14:09.572 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
12-02 12:14:09.573 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
12-02 12:14:09.829 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
12-02 12:14:10.000 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
12-02 12:14:10.002 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
12-02 12:14:10.002 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-02 12:14:10.003 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
12-02 12:14:10.003 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
12-02 12:14:10.003 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
12-02 12:14:10.007 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xdf605480: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
12-02 12:14:10.009 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:10.208 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:10.371 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:10.412 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:10.449 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:10.963 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:13.418 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
12-02 12:14:13.421 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
12-02 12:14:13.421 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
12-02 12:14:13.421 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
12-02 12:14:13.433 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: Accessing hidden field Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->theUnsafe:Lsun/misc/Unsafe; (light greylist, reflection)
12-02 12:14:13.512 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5071712
12-02 12:14:13.592 19151-19189/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/ALREADY LOGGED?:: false
12-02 12:14:13.592 19151-19189/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/URL POST:: http://www.pitchkings.net/pets/Services/signout.php
12-02 12:14:13.595 19151-19189/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/LOADING COOKIE:: No cookies were found
12-02 12:14:13.781 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:13.827 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:13.832 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:13.837 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/chatty: uid=10088(com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp) RenderThread identical 1 line
12-02 12:14:13.856 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:13.911 19151-19186/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
12-02 12:14:14.276 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:14.373 19151-19186/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/adghali.petsap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
12-02 12:14:14.378 19151-19189/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/RESPONSE CODE POST:: 200
12-02 12:14:14.384 19151-19189/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp V/CatalogClient: Logged out successfully
12-02 12:14:14.386 19151-19189/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/COOKIE:: Cleared all cookies
12-02 12:14:14.386 19151-19189/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/COOKIE:: PHPSESSID=91e9786974f3381f286fd443d513c50f; path=/
12-02 12:14:14.387 19151-19189/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/STORED COOKIE:: PHPSESSID: 91e9786974f3381f286fd443d513c50f
12-02 12:14:14.387 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/POST:: EXECUTING ON POST EXEC: Logged out successfully
12-02 12:14:14.387 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp E/Response: Logged out successfully
12-02 12:14:14.449 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@6ace48e
12-02 12:14:14.527 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:14.631 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:14.655 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/chatty: uid=10088(com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp) RenderThread identical 1 line
12-02 12:14:14.662 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:14.687 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:14.854 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:16.787 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:23.860 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:25.196 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 7256 bytes, containing 1 windows, 30 views
12-02 12:14:29.526 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 7368 bytes, containing 1 windows, 30 views
12-02 12:14:34.765 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/Params: password@:@iamjamesbond@-@email@:@jamesbond@gmail.com@-@
12-02 12:14:34.767 19151-19205/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/ALREADY LOGGED?:: false
12-02 12:14:34.767 19151-19205/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/URL POST:: http://www.pitchkings.net/pets/Services/signin.php
12-02 12:14:34.816 19151-19205/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/LOADING COOKIE:: No cookies were found
12-02 12:14:34.822 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:35.229 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:35.402 19151-19205/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/RESPONSE CODE POST:: 200
12-02 12:14:35.403 19151-19205/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp V/CatalogClient: {"token":"6d6542ccef1b068199c4bacdfaf65d8e"}
12-02 12:14:35.404 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/POST:: EXECUTING ON POST EXEC: {"token":"6d6542ccef1b068199c4bacdfaf65d8e"}
12-02 12:14:35.404 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp E/Response: {"token":"6d6542ccef1b068199c4bacdfaf65d8e"}
12-02 12:14:35.404 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/Token:: 6d6542ccef1b068199c4bacdfaf65d8e
12-02 12:14:35.540 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:36.674 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
12-02 12:14:36.783 19151-19221/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0
12-02 12:14:36.783 19151-19221/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0
12-02 12:14:36.795 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:36.808 19151-19221/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0
12-02 12:14:36.833 19151-19221/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/chatty: uid=10088(com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp) glide-disk-cach identical 2 lines
12-02 12:14:36.833 19151-19221/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0
12-02 12:14:36.985 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:14:37.006 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:15:14.590 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 7256 bytes, containing 1 windows, 30 views
12-02 12:15:14.598 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:15:14.608 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:15:19.434 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 7320 bytes, containing 1 windows, 30 views
12-02 12:15:21.389 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/Params: password@:@sdf@-@email@:@asdasd@-@
12-02 12:15:21.389 19151-19239/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/ALREADY LOGGED?:: true
12-02 12:15:21.389 19151-19239/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/URL POST:: http://www.pitchkings.net/pets/Services/signin.php
12-02 12:15:21.421 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:15:21.437 19151-19239/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/LOADING COOKIE:: No cookies were found
12-02 12:15:21.876 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:15:21.909 19151-19239/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/RESPONSE CODE POST:: 200
12-02 12:15:21.910 19151-19239/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/COOKIE:: PHPSESSID=1ddd47b94d4eb04526f151ff02ade5b9; path=/
12-02 12:15:21.910 19151-19151/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp I/POST:: EXECUTING ON POST EXEC: 
12-02 12:15:21.958 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
12-02 12:15:22.367 19151-19172/com.example.mohammadghali.petsapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf605480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf603710)
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)
Cheers